# Do you use "curious" as a word to express intrigue or other such emotion?

Tags: word-usage

Could I use it in this context for example:

> I went to the science fair last week; I found it very *curious*.

Or in a context like this:

> And then John said that being killed by lightning wasn't possible.
> Hmmm... *curious*. I always thought getting struck by 3 million volts of
> electricity would elicit that kind of response.

Comment: Both your examples sound fine to me. I'd probably expect a follow on from your first sentence, explaining what you thought was peculiar about it. In the second one it gives the impression you're doubting what John has said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though *intriguing* may be a more accurate word, ***curious*** can also be used with this meaning:

> arousing or exciting speculation, interest, or attention through being inexplicable or highly unusual; odd; strange:
>
> - a *curious* sort of person; a *curious* scene. ([Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/curious))

The most common way to use it though is saying:

> How curious!

or

> How curious that...

How curious [!] that *I found it intriguing* is actually [less common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%20found%20it%20curious%2Chow%20curious%2CI%20found%20it%20intriguing&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20found%20it%20curious%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chow%20curious%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20found%20it%20intriguing%3B%2Cc0) than *I found it curious*:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't ever hear the word curious being used as an adjective, as in your first example.  Curious is used as a state of being, like "I am curious" or "that makes me curious".  In the first sentence I would say "I found it intriguing" instead.